# Run .hover() inside variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to write some code like this:

```
var clickAction = function(){
    $('#OL_Icon_55').append("<em class='well'>Hello World</em>");
}
$("body").one("mouseenter",clickAction);
```

And I want to hide `Hello World` string when mouse hover around `#OL_Icon_55`, than the code will be look like this :

```
var clickAction = function(){
    $('#OL_Icon_55').append("<em class='well'>Hello World</em>", function() {
        $(this).hover(function () {
            $(".well").hide();
        });
    });
}
$("body").one("mouseenter",clickAction);
```

But that is not working for me. Does anyone have a little more idea or correct that code so that hover function can work?

Comment: The `append` method doesn't have a callback. Also FYI `hover()` is going to deprecated in the next jQuery.

Comment: can you give me some example so that code can work?

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? Why an event just once on body? Something seems wrong with your logic...

Comment: Yeah you might as well hardcode that html in..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EeGYs/1/).

'Hello World' will be shown if the mouse is inside `#OL_Icon_55`.

Here's the JS:

```
var $OL = $('#OL_Icon_55'),
    $span = $("<span class='well'>Hello World</span>");

$("body").one("mouseenter", function() {
    $OL.append($span);
});

$OL.mouseenter(function () {
    $span.show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    $span.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Stole most the code from @depot.  But much shorter

```
$(function(){  // <-- on dom ready
    var $OL = $('#OL_Icon_55'),
    $span = $("<span class='well'>Hello World</span>");  

    $("body").one("mouseenter", function() {  // <-- on one mouse enter
        $OL.append($span);  // <-- append span
    });

    $OL.hover(function () {  // <-- on hover
        $span.toggle();  // <-- toggle (show/hide) span
    });   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EeGYs/3/

Comment: liked your solution, since doesn't hide the div when you hover over it. +1